# What's the difference between many CONTAINS and only one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a search engine that build query dynamically to an SQL Server database and I'm having different results with these queries:

```
CONTAINS('goal AND of AND Chelsea');
```

AND

```
CONTAINS('goal') AND CONTAINS('of') AND CONTAINS('Chelsea')
```

The first one returns me results and the second nothing.

I used these commands for Full-Text Search engine accept noise words:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Now, the first sql command is working fine, but the second, that is the command my search engine generates, doesn't work.

Comment: Neither of those returns any results for me. "of" isn't even indexed. http://i.stack.imgur.com/0My1H.png

Comment: I'm just testing this! I enabled It using "sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1"

Comment: I can reproduce those results now. But "of" still isn't indexed. So looks like it just ignores it in the larger query but when used as a single term it returns false. (as of isn't even in the index the alternative would be to return all rows)

Comment: @Martin Smith I edited my question and It works.

Comment: That config option doesn't do what you need then. You'll need to do `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[testtable] SET STOPLIST = OFF` to include the noise words in the full text index.

Answer (score 2):

"of" is a noise word.

I can reproduce your results with "transform noise words" on and inserting the following into a full text indexed table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[testtable]
            ([id],
             [text])
VALUES      (1,'goal'),
            (2,'Chelsea'),
            (3,'of'),
            (4,'Drogba of Chelsea scored a goal')
```

After the index is populated

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(db_id('fts'), object_id('testtable'))
```

Returns

```
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
|            keyword             | display_term | column_id | document_count |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
| 0x006300680065006C007300650061 | chelsea      |         2 |              2 |
| 0x00640072006F006700620061     | drogba       |         2 |              1 |
| 0x0067006F0061006C             | goal         |         2 |              2 |
| 0x00730063006F007200650064     | scored       |         2 |              1 |
| 0xFF                           | END OF FILE  |         2 |              4 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
```

From which I conclude that this option does not affect what is indexed - simply how the queries are treated.

```
CONTAINS('goal AND of AND Chelsea');
```

becomes

```
CONTAINS('goal AND Chelsea');
```

after ignoring the noise word.

```
CONTAINS('of')
```

cannot be answered from the index and SQL Server clearly decides it is better to return `false` than return `true` for a load of rows that don't event contain that text.

I'm not sure why it doesn't evaluate as `unknown` rather than `false` though

```
WHERE NOT CONTAINS([text],'of')
```

returns all rows - including those containing the term!

[image]

If you can't alter your query to use the pattern that works the way you want then you will need to get around the issue by including the noise words in the full text index.

After running

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[testtable] SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

and rebuilding the index it works the way you want.